# Rails - nesting routes within the same controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm totally confused trying to route my app. I have a bunch of events, and each should have a photo gallery.

However I would like to keep everything within the same EVENT controller (btw, another question - how reasonable is that?). So the user can go on the Edit Event page and have a menu on the left side with links, one of which will be his gallery.

So I've added this to my event controller:

```
def gallery
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
end
```

The URI should be (I guess?): site/event/777/gallery/edit

How can I route that? And what will be the _path?

Thank you for any help

Comment: A gallery is not an event. You should create a separate controller for galleries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of no good reason to do this.  Creating another file is trivial, have a GalleriesController with the usual show/edit/update/etc methods.

In your routes:

```
resources :events do
  resources :galleries
```

galleries_controller.rb:

```
class GalleriesController < ApplicationController

  # GET /events/1/galleries/1/edit
  def edit
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @gallery = @event.galleries.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer: two questions: how can I skip the *1* in galleries/1/edit, since the user only has one gallery, and what does the edit gallery path look like?

Comment: In the routes, make `resources :galleries` into `resource :gallery`.  Now it's a singular resource in the event, and doesn't pass an ID in.  `rake routes` will show you the change as well.

Comment: Well, I went with the way you proposed in your first answer, and now my navigation link from the side menu that points to the gallery looks like events//galleries, now I'm really puzzled

Comment: Not sure on that.  You're close!  I recommend reading [this cover-to-cover](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).  It's pretty short, and should cover the various ways your routes will end up.  Run `rake routes` to see if you ended up w/what you expected, and on the left hand side the prefixes to the url/path helpers will be next to the route you want.

Answer (score 1):

The following configuration in your `config/routes.rb` should give you what you want:

```
resources :events do 
  resources :galleries
end
```

And this will give you `event_galleries_path`. And, this will give you `event_galleries_path`.  Following are the seven paths the above configuration will provide:

```
      event_galleries GET    /events/:event_id/galleries(.:format)              galleries#index
                      POST   /events/:event_id/galleries(.:format)              galleries#create
    new_event_gallery GET    /events/:event_id/galleries/new(.:format)          galleries#new
   edit_event_gallery GET    /events/:event_id/galleries/:id/edit(.:format)     galleries#edit
        event_gallery GET    /events/:event_id/galleries/:id(.:format)          galleries#show
                      PUT    /events/:event_id/galleries/:id(.:format)          galleries#update
                      DELETE /events/:event_id/galleries/:id(.:format)          galleries#destroy
```

The edit named route is: `edit_event_gallery_path`.

Then instead of adding the `gallery` method in your `EventsController`, so you'd create your `edit`, `show` and other other actions in your `GalleriesController`.

```
# /events/:event_id/galleries/:id/edit
def edit
  @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
end

# /events/:event_id/galleries/:id
def show 
  @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])

  # And your galleries, something like this
  @galleries = @event.galleries.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But I would like one default gallery to be already created, without user participation?